# Using clojure to scrape a web page with dynamic content

Tags: clojure, web-scraping

For learning purpose, I am trying to use Clojure to scrape data from the following [site](http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/#/?company=6947&category=all&sub_category=all&alphabetical=All).

I would like to know how do to get the data in the table "bm_center bm_dataTable".

The challenge I have is that this table's DOM is not available on this page's html source, because it is dynamically generated in the browser.

How do I get the hml source of the table?

I know very little about web programming but am willing to learn. Thank you in advance for your patience.

Comment: Good to know that you are willing to learn, but this question requires you to learn different concepts which isn't what SO is for.

Comment: @Ankur So what if she (or he) didn't know. It is an honest question.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. It's a straightforward question. Sara, the "enlive" project and its documentation might be of help to you. It is a Clojure library for html scraping and templating, and there are a few good tutorials about screen scraping. https://github.com/cgrand/enlive

Comment: To add to this: Since the data you want is dynamically generated, you should look for the Ajax call that pulls in the data. That happens in this file: http://www.bursamalaysia.com/javascripts/bursa_wrmp/page_company_announcements.js -- Somewhere in there, a variable "url" is defined that points to the datatable, which turns out to be this: http://ws.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/announcements_listing_f.html -- that is a json document with HTML inside it, which you can scrape using Enlive.

Comment: @Bill: I didn't say that this isn't a honest question, what I said was that it isn't a practical question on SO

Comment: @Ankur I'm not sure I agree. The OP accepted a relatively short answer that describes the concepts and offers some suggestions about how to deal with the situation. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM is normally a thing that lives in the browser. The browser pulls down the same text that you're seeing in Clojure and then builds the DOM that it uses to render the page etc...

You can manipulate the text manually to pull out what you want by writing Clojure code. You could use a Java library like JSoup to extract information from the HTML. The standard Java libraries also come with an HTML parser, but I would avoid it. It is difficult to use and doesn't really bring much benefit.